# Retain formulas when refreshing data

Tags: mysql, vba, excel-formula

We have VBA code for refreshing data from MySql database to Excel.

The formulas that existed previously in Excel are disappearing after refreshing data from the database.

We tried using the below code to skip the rows that have formulas, and other rows are refreshed.

1.

```
Worksheets("HSE").Range("D10:O11,D15:O16,D20:O25,D29:O30,D32:O33,D36:O45").ClearContents
```

2.

```
Dim rConstants As Range

Set rConstants = Worksheets("HSE").Range("D9:O45").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
rConstants.ClearContents
```

but both did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are your formulae always going to be in the same location?  If so, what you might consider doing is loading your raw data from MySql into one worksheet, then setting up a second worksheet where each cell either references the corresponding cell in the first sheet or has the formula and applies it against the corresponding cell in the first sheet.

Comment: Thanks for response. yes formulae are going to be in the same location. but the answer you gave is difficult for us to implement. because we have more number of sheets to refresh and more users who use this data. so we can not ask them to use 2 sheets for every refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you separate out the 'data dump' page from the 'formula page'. Users should be aware that they are not to directly edit the 'data dump' pages, and should instead pull information onto their other page using SUMIFS, INDEX(MATCH), etc..

This will allow you refresh your data pages without impacting your users' formulas, and as an additional benefit will more cleanly allow audit/review of a user's work.